# php how to get xml tags

Tags: php, xml

I tried to find it myself but didn't succeed.

Part of my code is to get xml from web-service and print some of the data.

I want to get the all hotel details (tags) where hotel id = 285

and also, how do i get flight "num" where inner hotel tag is "678" ?

```
<packages>

    <pck type="vacation">

        <flight num="1">
            <date></date>
            <airline></airline>
            <hotels>
                <hotel>
                    <number>1</number>
                    <id>285</id>
                    <price>250 USD</price>
                </hotel>

                <hotel>
                    <number>2</number>
                    <id>678</id>
                    <price>480 USD</price>
                </hotel>                
            </hotels>
        </flight>

        <flight num="2">
        </flight>

        <hotel_details>
            <hotel id="285">
                <name>Alexander</name>
                <location></location>
                <rate></rate>
            </hotel>

            <hotel id="678">
                <name>Leonardo</name>
                <location></location>
                <rate></rate>
            </hotel>            
        </hotel_details>        

    </pck>


    <pck type="ski">

    </pck>

</packages>
```

Comment: You certainly should use a xml parser for this. Take a look at SimpleXML.

Comment: This sounds like a good example for using XPath.

Comment: too many ways to get the data...it's hard. I tried both of them without any luck. can you please show me? @arkascha

Comment: We aren't going to write the code for you but if you edit your question and show us what you have tried we'll guide you towards a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure your XML is in a parsable format.  Rather than this:

    <hotel id="285">
        <name>Alexander</name>
        <location></location>
        <rate></rate>
    </hotel>

I'd do this so you can iterate over the hotel node, checking for the value of id:

    <hotel>
        <id>285</id>
        <name>Alexander</name>
        <location></location>
        <rate></rate>
    </hotel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has DOMDocument Class (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

It is pretty straight forward:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

// convert to xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// search
$search_results = $xpath->query('//flight//hotel[@id=678]');
```

Read more at:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp
2. [Document Object Model](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)